# C# loop question

Tags: c#

I have two textboxes with a integer value in each textbox.  I need to find all even values between the start and stop box using a loop.

How would I do this?

Comment: What are these boxes? This sounds like a homework question.

Comment: This question is clear, if simple, and has an answer. It may be homework, but it is a real, answerable question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var from = Convert.ToInt32(box1.Text);
var to = Convert.ToInt32(box2.Text);
for(int i = from; i <= to; i++)
{
    if (i % 2 == 0)
    {
        SomehowOutput(i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int start = ...;
int end = ...;
for (int i = start; i <= end; i++) {
   // number is even
   if (i % 2 == 0) {

   }
}
```

The question is very unclear, but I assume you're talking about testing for even numbers within a loop..

Answer (score 0):

One could now elaborate on TextBox.Text or int.Parse( textBox.Text ) or the modula operation, but since they are just boxes I fear you haved to resort to higher math...

Answer (score 0):

```
int start = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
int end = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);

for (int i = start; i <= end; i++)            
    if (i % 2 == 0)
        textBox3.Text += i.ToString() + " ";
```